# How to write summaries for multiple runs in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

If you look at the Tensorboard [dashboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/cifar.html) for the cifar10 demo, it shows data for multiple runs. I am having trouble finding a good example showing how to set the graph up to output data in this fashion. I am currently doing something similar to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py), but it seems to be combining data from runs and whenever a new run starts I see the warning on the console:

> WARNING:root:Found more than one graph event per run.Overwritting the graph with the newest event

Answer (score 31):

The solution turned out to be simple (and probably a bit obvious), but I'll answer anyway. The writer is instantiated like this:

```py
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.log_dir, sess.graph_def)
```

The events for the current run are written to the specified directory. Instead of having a fixed value for the `logdir` parameter, just set a variable that gets updated for each run and use that as the name of a sub-directory inside the log directory:

```py
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('%s/%s' % (FLAGS.log_dir, run_var), sess.graph_def)
```

Then just specify the root `log_dir` location when starting tensorboard via the `--logdir` parameter.

Comment: Did you ever have issues where having multiple runs suppresses the summaries of one/two past runs? Sometimes, the new run causes past runs' summaries to go completely blank. Usually, only 1 or 2 summaries will correctly show the data for all runs simultaneously.

Comment: I haven't seen that particular behavior, though I have seen it not display the current run. Does restarting tensorboard help?

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with [`MonitoredTrainingSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MonitoredTrainingSession)?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/tensorboard/README.md#runs-comparing-different-executions-of-your-model), you can specify multiple log directories when running tensorboard. Alternatively, you can create multiple `run` subfolder in the log directory to visualize different plots in the same graph.